# Set data from method in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to set an data from a method. I am using fetch to get an rest data. But, when I try to set the data, using this.item = 'test' doesn't work. So, when my this.item is inside ".then" doesn't working. But when is out of ".then" it working... But I need to use a rest call to get the data...

```
Vue.component('internal_menu', {
   props: ['list'],
   data: function () {
      return {
         item: '1'
      }
   },
methods: {
   teste(event)
   {
       event.preventDefault();
       var payload = {
           method: 'GET',
           headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
           credentials: 'same-origin'    // or credentials: 'include'  
       }
       const url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
       "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('"+ this.list +"')/Items? 
       $select=Title,Id,Link,Icone&$orderby=Title%20asc";
       fetch(url,payload)
          .then((resp) => resp.json())
          .then(function(data) 
          {
              let items = data.d.results;
              this.item = 'teste';// this not working here
          })
        . catch(function(error) {
             console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
          });
          this.item = 'tst123'; //this working here
     },

 },
 template: `
    <div id='tst'>
       <h3>{{list}} - {{item}}</h3>
        <button v-on:click="teste">Try Me</button>
    </div>
`,
 mounted: function () {
    this.getMenuData();
 }
})

new Vue({
   el: "#app"
})
```

thanks
Everton

Comment: I resolved my problem. I created an var self and get 'this' before to enter in callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
.then(function(data) 
      {
          let items = data.d.results;
          this.item = 'teste';// this not working here
      })
```

Your closure's reference to `this` is the within the context of the anonymous function. Instead, you need to use the `fat arrow` function in order to maintain the context of the `Component`.

```
.then((data) => {
    let items = data.d.results;
    this.item = 'test';
})
```

Comment: I initially thought it was an `async/await` issue but I do not see where is he calling the `teste()` method.

Comment: @RuChernChong In the click function of the button in the template.